# Gnu/Linux command to list all users who has access to one folder

Tags: linux, command-line

I was trying to find all the users in my Gnu/Linux system that have access to one particular folder.

I tried

```
$ ls -ld */
dr-xr-xr-x.   2 root root     28672 Mar 20 21:33 bin/
dr-xr-xr-x.   4 root root      4096 Mar 16 16:02 boot/
```

I tried `ls -ldd */` , but it list only 1 row for one folder with the user name with which it created.

But I was expecting to list one folder each will show all users names who can access this folder

Eg:

```
$ 
dr-xr-xr-x.   2 user1 user1     28672 Mar 20 21:33 bin/
dr-xr-xr-x.   2 user2 user2      28672 Mar 20 21:33 bin/
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific to the meaning of "has access"? Is it `r`ead access? `w`rite access? e`x`ecute access? Any other type of access?

Comment: Since the directories are readable by "other", everyone has access.

Comment: What are the permissions of the parent folder(s)?

Comment: @PauloTomé ls -ld */. will show the access (dr-xr-xr-x) at the very left side of output.I was looking for any command that will show a similar output but to find all the users who has access to one specific folder.

Comment: @glennjackman Thank you, but any way to list all users who may access this folder?

Comment: @glennjackman assume this is a parent folder, in that case any commands to list all users who may access this folder. or any commands to check if useri has access to this folder alteast ?

Comment: If you are talking groups ... you will need to loop though each userid defined through `getent` and issue a `id` to get the groups the userid belongs to, then compare the directory group with userid groups

Comment: @rr0ss0rr could you paste the commands also. I am new to Linux (Fedora). I have a list of users with me, I can run the commands from admin terminal for each user for this folder. Please share the full command.

Comment: I'm on a Mac which does it differently, but look at `getent passwd` to get the list of userids then issue a `id -n` _userid_ to get the groups the user belongs to.

Comment: The reason I ask about parent directories: if you have `/a/b/c/d` and `b` has perms `drwx------` then even is `d` is world-readable, only the user of `b` can access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and Dirty and only tested on a Mac (which doesn't use getent).  I replaced getent with the mac command to test "`dscl . -ls /Users`"

```
chkgrp=$1
for userid in $(getent passwd); do
   echo "$(id -Gn $userid)" | grep -wq $chkgrp
   [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo "$userid is in the $chkgrp group"
done
```